# optional search parameters in sql query and rows with null values

Tags: c#, mysql

Ok here is my problem :

Before i start the description, let me to tell you that I have googled up a lot and I am posting this question for a good optimal solution :)

i am building a rest service on WCF to get userProfiles... the user can filter userProfiles by giving something like userProfiles?location=London

now i have the following method

```
GetUserProfiles(string firstname, string lastname, string age, string location)
```

the sql query string i built is:
`select firstname, lastname, .... from profiles where (firstName like '%{firstname}%') AND (lastName like '%{lastName}%')` ....and so on with all variables being replaced by string formatter.

Problem with this is that it filters any row having firstname, lastname, age or location having a null value....

doing something like `(firstName like '%{firstName}%' OR firstName IS NULL)` would be tedious and the statement would become unmaintanable! (in this example there are only 4 arguments, but in my actual method there are 10)

What would be the best solution for this?....How is this situation usually handled?

Database used : MySql

Comment: Have you considered using LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: no i have not yet considered linq to sql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [COALESCE(value,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
coalesce(firstName, '') like '%{firstname}%'
```

Comment: `COALESCE()` is basically an O(n) lookup as no indexes will be used.

Answer (score 2):

It's a fundamental property of `NULL` that when you compare it to *anything*—including `NULL`—it returns `false`, which is why what you're doing doesn't work.

So the first question to answer is: why do you want a row with a `NULL` `lastname` be returned when they enter a `lastname` of "smith"? Possibly you mean that *either* the firstname *or* the lastname needs to match to be returned, in which case you're not running the correct query. The most naive solution is:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, ....
FROM profiles
WHERE IFNULL(firstName LIKE'%{firstname}%'
OR lastName LIKE '%{lastName}%'
```

Now this will work for several hundreds and possibly several thousand rows but won't scale beyond that for several reasons:

1. `OR`s are typically woeful in terms of performance. Avoid them where possible. If you look at database applications written by experienced programmers you probably won't find a single `OR` condition (except from those who proselytize the virtues of `OR` on the back of having once written a guestbook application that has 3 users and 2 hits a month);
2. Doing a `LIKE` with a `%` at the front will mean no indexes will be sued.

There are several solutions to (2). Probably the easiest in MySQL is to use [full text searching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) on MyISAM tables. It won't find matches like "Johannes" if you type in "han" but it is generally sufficient.

Often you deal with `OR` conditions by using either `UNION` or (preferably) `UNION ALL` on multiple queries. For example:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, ....
FROM profiles
WHERE firstName LIKE'%{firstname}%'
AND lastName LIKE '%{lastName}%'
UNION ALL
SELECT firstname, lastname, ....
FROM profiles
WHERE firstName LIKE'%{firstname}%'
AND lastname IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT firstname, lastname, ....
FROM profiles
WHERE firstName IS NULL
AND lastName LIKE '%{lastName}%'
UNION ALL
SELECT firstname, lastname, ....
FROM profiles
WHERE firstName IS NULL
AND lastName IS NULL
```

Looks big and ugly but `UNION ALL` scales extremely well (ignoring the `%` at the start of the `LIKE` criteria). It's basically concatenating (in this case) four queries. A `UNION` will do an implicit `DISTINCT` on the result rows but we know there'll be no overlap here because we're varying checking for `NULL`.

Another possibility is not to treat `NULL` as something you want to search for. This is a far better and more intuitive solution (imho). If someone types in a lastname of "Smith" do you really want rows with a `NULL` lastname showing up?

Or do you want them to show up because you might've got a match on the first name? If so, you want a slightly different query. For example:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, ....
FROM profiles
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id 
  FROM profiles
  WHERE firstName LIKE'%{firstname}%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id 
  FROM profiles
  WHERE lastName LIKE '%{lastName}%'
)
```

Comment: @glenn: like I said, the four union variant is going to be mostly pointless **in this case** because the criteria won't use indexes anyway but if you were using indexes then that's a different story. The bigger issue is whether you're running the right query and whether your data model is suboptimal or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
select firstname, lastname, ....
from profiles
where (coalesce(firstName, '') like '%{firstname}%')
AND (coalesce(lastName, '') like '%{lastName}%')
```

Comment: `COALESCE()` is basically an O(n) lookup as no indexes will be used.

Comment: Yes, obviously, but you can't use indexes anyway because of the `LIKE '%foo%'` so it seems to be a moot point here. The index can be used with `LIKE 'foo%' but not if there's a wildcard at the start. If performance is an issue here, a full text index should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could always disallow null values in the first place - after all, everybody must be alive for some positive number of years and be somewhere geographically.

If you absolutely must allow nulls, then either use `COALESCE`, as others have suggested, or possibly `IFNULL` which is MySQL specific and may be slightly more optimal since it takes exactly 2 paramters.